# Problem occur when use array of objects in filter function React

Tags: reactjs

I try to get data from the backend and view data in the frontend. To do this I try this code.

```
function ViewPost() {
  const { postId } = useParams();
  console.log(postId);

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getOnePost();
  }, []);

  const getOnePost = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`/buyerGetOnePost/${postId}`);
      console.log(response);
      const allPost = response.data.onePost;
      setPosts(allPost);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
    }
  };
  console.log(posts);

  console.log(posts.wasteItemList);

  const [offers, getOffers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllOffers();
  }, []);

  const getAllOffers = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(`/viewPendingSellerOffers`)
      .then((response) => {
        const allNotes = response.data.existingOffers;
        getOffers(allNotes);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
  };
  console.log(offers);

  const wasteItem = offers?.filter(
    (wasteItem) =>
      wasteItem.status === "accepted" &&
      wasteItem.wasteItemsListId === posts?.wasteItemList?._id,
  );
  console.log(wasteItem);
}
```

I call the first API and get a specific post data and this post has an array of objects called `wasteItemList`. When I use this code `console.log(posts.wasteItemList)`, I get length 2 array of objects. This is an image of this result.

[image: WasteItemList array of objects]

Then I call the second API and get length 8 array of objects. This is an image of this result.

[image: Results of second API call]

Then I try to filter data using this code `const wasteItem = offers?.filter(wasteItem => wasteItem.status==='accepted' && wasteItem.wasteItemsListId===posts?.wasteItemList?._id)`. But this filter function give an empty array. What is the reason for this problem? How do I solve this?

Comment: It's kind of confusing that your function is called `getOnePost` and it touches a state atom that's named in plural (`setPosts`). Which one is it? Is it one post or multiple posts?

Comment: Also, the _setter_ for your `offers` is `getOffers`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, your naming seems a little off. A function that supposedly gets one post assigns to a state atom that's plural, and your setter for `offers` is `getOffers`.

Here's a simplification/rewrite of your component that *assumes* `post` is supposed to be singular and `offers` is in plural. Also, you were missing the data dependency `postId` for the `useEffect`.

In addition, since `wasteItem` is singular, I assume you want the first matching offer, not all of them, so `.find()` is the thing.

```
function ViewPost() {
  const { postId } = useParams();
  const [post, setPost] = useState(undefined);
  const [offers, setOffers] = useState(undefined);
  useEffect(() => {
    setPost(undefined);
    axios
      .get(`/buyerGetOnePost/${postId}`)
      .then((resp) => setPost(resp.data.onePost))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, [postId]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`/viewPendingSellerOffers`)
      .then((response) => setOffers(response.data.existingOffers))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, []);

  if (post === undefined || offers === undefined) {
    return <>Loading...</>;
  }

  const wasteItem = offers.find(
    (wasteItem) =>
      wasteItem.status === "accepted" &&
      wasteItem.wasteItemsListId === post.wasteItemList?._id,
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Post: {JSON.stringify(post)}</div>
      <div>Offers: {JSON.stringify(offers)}</div>
      <div>Waste Item: {JSON.stringify(wasteItem)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```